# trying to call a string that is assigned within a function

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.x, call

I have set a string called 'charge' within a function but when I call 'charge' in the main body I get a traceback call saying that 'charge' is not defined. I would like to know if it is possible to call the string from outside of the function and if it is not, is there another way to get the data held within charge?

```
def service (x, y, z):
    print ('How many animals are being provided for?')
    nodogs = input ('-----> ')

    if nodogs == '1':
        charge = 'x'

    elif nodogs == '2':
        charge = 'y'

    elif nodogs == '3':
        charge = 'z'

    x = int (x)
    y = int (y)
    z = int (z)

# the call for the string is later on but I think that part is irrelevant.
#If it is not, please say and I will post it.
```

I am a novice and am only trying out simple code. if an advanced feature is required, please explain the feature as I am unlikely to know it already,

Thanks in advance - TGSpike

Comment: Is all that code within the `service` function? (If so it should be indented)

Comment: yes it is, I will correct that now. It is indednted in the program, just not on the website

Comment: In any case, you should put the line `return charge` at the end of the function, and then when you call the function, do `charge = service(x, y, z)` (with `x` `y` `z` set however you're using them). This will return the value of `charge` to your main program, and put it in the variable `charge`. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you, this has really helped.

Comment: BTW, will the 'return' feature work for more than one string?

Comment: Yes, you can do `return x, y` and then `x, y = service(x, y, z)`. This is called tuple unpacking. I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: When you assign a name to a value inside a function, that name only exists inside of that function. The name is local to the function, not global.  To learn more about this, search for Python scoping or Python namespace.

Comment: You will likely have more questions related to the rest of your code since I do not think that `charge = 'x'` is going to do what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the line

```
return charge
```

at the end of the function, and then when you call the function, do

```
charge = service(x, y, z)
```

(with `x` `y` `z` set however you're using them). This will return the value of `charge` to your main program, and put it in the variable `charge`. If you want to do this with multiple variables, you can do

```
return x, y
```

and

```
x, y = service(x, y, z)
```

This is called tuple unpacking.